# ATS Error: "ATS policy requires the use of a secure connection", despite plist

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a request for an http domain, and despite having

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>my-private-domain.kubernetes.intranet%2f:9090</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

at my info.plist for the app target, XCode 12.5.1 keeps me showing the error

```
Task <C5F9EA01-9790-43ED-89B0-EE07341B4D84>.<4> finished with error [-1022] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.
```

I needed to perform this request after updating to 12.5.1 and also tried Clean Build Folder and removing-reinstalling the app. Does someone knows if it's a policy change? (maybe only HTTPS are now allowed even in non-production targets?). The answers I found here only cites `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, `NSExceptionDomains`, `NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion/NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` and `NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy`. There's something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `info.plist` includes the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` key, the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` is ignored and treated as false.  So removing the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` should allow all arbitrary loads.

Relevant section from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsallowsarbitraryloads):

> In iOS 10 and later and macOS 10.12 and later, the value of the
> NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key is ignored—and the default value of NO used
> instead—if any of the following keys are present in your app’s
> Information Property List file:
>
> - NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia
> - NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent
> - NSAllowsLocalNetworking